# Integral of Kepler problem (SOLVED)

Tags: classical-mechanics, integration

> I'm trying to resolve the elliptic integral that appears in the Kepler problem, i.e.,
>   \begin{align}
> I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha +\beta x+\gamma x^2}}.
> \end{align}
>   Goldstein says the the integral is
>   \begin{align}
> \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha +\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos \left(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma}}\right).
> \end{align}
>   I don't know how to resolve the integral.

***My attempt:*** 
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha +\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha-\frac{\beta^2}{4\gamma}+\gamma\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2}}
\end{align}
Changing variables like $x=\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\tan^2 \theta\rightarrow dx=\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}2\tan\theta \sec\theta\; d\theta$,
\begin{align}
\therefore I=\int\frac{\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}2\tan\theta\sec\theta\;d\theta}{\sqrt{\alpha-\frac{\beta^2}{4\gamma^2}+\gamma\left[\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}(\tan^2\theta+1)\right]^2}}=\int\frac{\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\tan\theta\sec\theta}{\sqrt{\alpha+\sec^4\theta}}\;d\theta=\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\int\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\alpha \cos^4\theta+1}}\;d\theta.
\end{align}

=================================================

**EDIT AND SOLUTION**

\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\gamma\left(\frac{\beta}{\gamma}x+x^2\right)}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha+\gamma\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4\gamma}}}
\end{align}
If $y=x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}$:
\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\alpha+\gamma y^2-\frac{\beta^2}{4\gamma}}}=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha\gamma-\beta^2}{4\gamma}+\gamma y^2}}
\end{align}
If $q=\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma$,
\begin{align}
I=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\gamma y^2-\frac{q}{4\gamma}}}
\end{align}
Then $y=-\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\cos\theta$ and $dy=\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\sin\theta\;d\theta$,
\begin{align}
\therefore I=\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2(-\gamma)}\int\frac{-\sin\theta\;d\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{q}{4\gamma}(\cos^2\theta-1)}}=\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2(-\gamma)}\int\frac{-\sin\theta\;d\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{q}{4(-\gamma)}(1-\cos^2\theta)}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\;\theta\\
\boxed{\therefore \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha +\beta x+\gamma x^2}}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}\arccos\left(-\frac{\beta+2\gamma x}{\sqrt{\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma}}\right)}
\end{align}

Comment: After completing the square, first do an affine change of variables $y=ax+b$ so that the thing in the square root becomes $c(1+y^2)$ for some constant $c$.  Then set $y=\cos(\theta)$.  You will find that the resulting integrand is just a constant.

Comment: I think this is an issue of pure mathematics. Methods of solution are found in standard calculus books. The context is irrelevant : replacing *Kepler* with *Nash* or *Darwin* makes absolutely no difference to the question. No physics is applied in the method of solution. I think this belongs on Mathematics SE.

Comment: @Yly, I obtained the result, but I'm missing something in the denominator: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}}$. After I completed squares, I think there's something about the discrminant $\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma$ that I cannot see that avoids me obtaining the full result.

Comment: @hyriusen I suggest you edit your work into the question.  The $1/\sqrt{-\gamma}$ should come from the first linear change of variables.

Comment: @hyriusen Also, I made a slight typo in the first comment: you want the thing in the square root to be $c(1-y^2)$.

Comment: @Yly, sorry if it is too noob, but I cannot obtain what you're saying. Check my procedure

\begin{align}
I&=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\alpha + \beta x+\gamma x^2}}\\
&= \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{\gamma}+\frac{\beta}{\gamma}x+x^2\right)}}\\
&=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\alpha-\frac{\beta^2}{4\gamma}\right)+\gamma\left(x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}\right)^2}}
\end{align}
If $y=x+\frac{\beta}{2\gamma}$:
\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{4\alpha\gamma-\beta^2}{4\gamma}+\gamma y^2}}\\
&=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\gamma y^2-\frac{\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma}{4\gamma}}}
\end{align}

Comment: If $q=\beta^2-4\alpha\gamma$, then $y=\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\cosh\theta$ and $dy=\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\sinh\theta\;d\theta$:
\begin{align}
I&=\int\frac{\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\sinh\theta\;d\theta}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{q}{4\gamma}\right)(\cosh^2\theta-1)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\theta
\end{align}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @hyriusen You've done nothing wrong.  But note that you'll get an $\text{arccosh}$ the way you're going, whereas the answer you want involves an $\arccos$.  The two are related by a factor of $\pm i$, which accounts for the missing sign.  To straighten out the sign, either use a $\cos$ substitution instead of a $\cosh$ substitution, or else just use the relationship between $\arccos$ and $\text{arccosh}$.  See this wolfram alpha link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos(x)%2Farccosh(x)

Comment: Indeed, if I use $\theta\to i\theta$ and $y=-\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\cosh\theta$, or if I use at the beginning $y=-\frac{\sqrt{q}}{2\gamma}\cos\theta$ I obtain the result, but I think there's a typo because there's a minus sign at the beginning of $1/\sqrt{-\gamma}\arccos(...)$.